# How to use MySql datatbase in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am using MySql database in ASP .NET using C#.
When I am trying to connect to any of the databases of MySql it's giving exception of
"Access denied for user root@localhost (using password NO)"

Connection string : 
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;User Id=root;database=sample");
I am using root with password...still it's saying NO Password

Comment: Please post your code and connection string.

Comment: is it localhost or remote connection

Comment: @apesa, either way it should work

Answer (score 1):

Since connecting seems to be the crux of your problem, be sure to use a connection string in the form:

```
string server = "XXX";
string database = "XXX";
string uid = "XXX";
string password = "XXX";
string connectionString =
    "Server=" + server + ";" +
    "Database=" + database + ";" +
    "Uid=" + uid + ";" +
    "Password=" + password + ";";
```

I've answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16503484/1810429) about using MySQL from C# that may be of further help by providing a little more context.

Also, be sure to print out or inspect `connectionString` with your debugger if you still have trouble.  Sometimes an error like you're seeing comes down to a simple flub that only becomes clear when you look at the full connection string you've built...and find that it is not what you expected.

Finally, be sure to test with a MySQL client too if trouble connecting persists.  As with looking at the connection string you've built to find a simple mistake, sometimes a credentials test outside of your code with a trusted client will reveal that the credentials...truly do not work like you expected.

Comment: I did same but it doesn't work